# Internal Error: null while running Scala Worksheet in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am getting exception while running Scala Worksheet in intellij

> Internal error: null
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.send(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcVI$sp(RemoteServerRunner.scala:33)
>   scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.run(RemoteServerRunner.scala:30)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.server.RemoteServerConnector.compileAndRun(RemoteServerConnector.scala:85)
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.processor.WorksheetCompiler$$anon$1.run(WorksheetCompiler.scala:78)
>   com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:196)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: Does this happen opening an empty worksheet, or when you write something specific on the worksheet?

Comment: What is your IntelliJ version and what is the Scala version you are using?  Have you tried changing the Scala version of the project, e.g., change the Scala version to 2.11.x if you are using 2.12.x?

Comment: sorry for late response.... It worked fine with latest latest JDK and scala version